# How to create schema and display record from new mongodb Collection in Meanjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, meanjs

i am developing an application on MEAN STACK. I want to show the data from an existing Collection in mongodb . But i am not getting the clear idea how to attach this Collection with mean stack.I have seen Article example and sign up process but little bit confuse.

How to set up new Collection with meanjs.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: And – what the heck is a table? Last time I had a look the organizational unit below a database was called a collection... Maybe you want to read [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: yes marks i want fetch data from a new collection.i have a collection named facilities .i want to create a schema in mean js and want to show the records on a new page. I have already imported the data from mysql table to mongo collection.

Answer (score 1):

The most used tool for this is [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). A mongoose model should be created on server side and in the server controllers you expose the required operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete etc). MEAN uses Mongoose.

On client side you create services which will access the server side controllers. The client side objects should have the same attributes as the server side model by convention.

I didn't use the MEAN Article example, but I used the Yeoman code generators to kick off some entities. I assume that the Article example follows the same pattern, so for server side model please check app/models, for the server side controllers check app/controllers, for client side services check public/modules/article/services.